# Unwanted [Nan] output in Python neural network

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, neural-network, sigmoid

newbie here. Just switched over from JS to Python to build Neural nets but getting [Nan] outputs from it.

The weird thing is that my sigmoid func. doesn't seem to encounter any overflow but the derivative causes chaos.

```
import numpy as np

def sigmoid(x):
  return x*(1-x)
  return 1/(1 + np.exp(-x))

#The function- 2

def Sigmoid_Derivative(x):
    return x * (1-x)

Training_inputs = np.array([[0,0,1], 
                            [1,1,1], 
                            [1,0,1], 
                            [0,1,1]])

Training_outputs = np.array([[0, 1, 1, 0]]).T

np.random.seed(1)

synaptic_weights = np.random.random((3, 1)) - 1

print ("Random starting synaptic weight:")
print (synaptic_weights)

for iteration in range(20000):
  Input_Layer = Training_inputs

  Outputs = sigmoid(np.dot(Input_Layer, synaptic_weights)) 

  erorr = Training_outputs - Outputs

  adjustments = erorr * Sigmoid_Derivative(Outputs)

  synaptic_weights += np.dot(Input_Layer.T, adjustments)

# The print declaration----------  
print ("Synaptic weights after trainig:")
print (synaptic_weights)

print ("Outputs after training: ")
print (Outputs)
```

This is the erorr message. I dunno why it Overflowing because the weights seem to be small enough.BTW **Pls give solutions in simple python as I am a   newbie** :--

```
Random starting synaptic weight:
[[-0.582978  ]
 [-0.27967551]
 [-0.99988563]]
/home/neel/Documents/VS-Code_Projects/Machine_Lrn(PY)/tempCodeRunnerFile.py:10: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in multiply
  return x * (1-x)
Synaptic weights after trainig:
[[nan]
 [nan]
 [nan]]
Outputs after training: 
[[nan]
 [nan]
 [nan]
 [nan]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least **two** issues with your code.

The first is the inexplicable use of 2 `return` statements in your `sigmoid` function, which should simply be:

```
def sigmoid(x):
  return 1/(1 + np.exp(-x))
```

which gives the correct result for `x=0` (0.5), and goes to 1 for large `x`:

```
sigmoid(0)
# 0.5
sigmoid(20)
# 0.99999999793884631
```

Your (wrong) sigmoid:

```
def your_sigmoid(x):
  return x*(1-x)
  return 1/(1 + np.exp(-x))
```

can easily lead to overflow:

```
your_sigmoid(20)
# -380
```

The other issue is that your derivative is wrong; it should be:

```
def Sigmoid_Derivative(x):
    return sigmoid(x) * (1-sigmoid(x))
```

See the [Derivative of sigmoid function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78575/derivative-of-sigmoid-function-sigma-x-frac11e-x) thread at Math.SE, as well as the discussion [here](https://gist.github.com/jovianlin/805189d4b19332f8b8a79bbd07e3f598).

Comment: the problem was that my model was overtrained significantly. Scaling the iterations down to 2500 did the trick. Though I will try to develop a code to figure out it's  iterations automatically