# How to increase accuracy of a Feed-forwardNeural Network?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, neural-network

I am having problem in increasing the accuracy of my Feed-Forward Neural network coded in python. I am not sure whether it's a genuine bug or just an incapability of my math functions but I am getting ambiguous outputs (like 0.5) No matter how much I increase the iterations....my code:-

```
from numpy import exp, array, random, dot

class NeuralNetwork():

    def __init__(self):
        random.seed(1)
        self.synaptic_weights = 2 * random.random((3, 1)) - 1     # MM reuslt = 3 (3 * 1)

    def Sigmoid(self, x):
        return 1 / (1 + exp(-x))

    def Sigmoid_Derivative(self, x):
        return x * (1 - x)

    def train(self, Training_inputs, Training_outputs, iterations):
        output = self.think(Training_inputs)
        print ("THe outputs are: -", output)
        erorr = Training_outputs - output

        adjustment = dot(Training_inputs.T, erorr * self.Sigmoid_Derivative(output))
        print ("The adjustments are:-", adjustment)
        self.synaptic_weights += output

    def think(self, inputs):
        Training_inputs = array(inputs)
        return self.Sigmoid(dot(inputs, self.synaptic_weights))

# phew! the class ends..

if __name__ == "__main__":

    neural_network = NeuralNetwork()
    print("Random startin weights", neural_network.synaptic_weights)

    Training_inputs = array([[1, 1, 1], 
                             [0, 0, 0], 
                             [1, 0, 1],])                 # 3 rows * 3 columns???

    Training_outputs = array([[1, 1, 0]]).T

    neural_network.train(Training_inputs, Training_outputs, 0)

    print ("New synaptic weights after training: ")
    print (neural_network.synaptic_weights)

    # Test the neural network with a new situation.
    print ("Considering new situation [1, 0, 0] -> ?: ")
    print (neural_network.think(array([1, 0, 0])))
```

**While these are my outputs:=>**

```
[Running] python -u "/home/neel/Documents/VS-Code_Projects/Machine_Lrn(PY)/test.py"
Random startin weights [[-0.16595599]
 [ 0.44064899]
 [-0.99977125]]
THe outputs are: - [[0.3262757 ]
 [0.5       ]
 [0.23762817]]
The adjustments are:- [[0.10504902]
 [0.14809799]
 [0.10504902]]
New synaptic weights after training: 
[[ 0.16031971]
 [ 0.94064899]
 [-0.76214308]]
Considering new situation [1, 0, 0] -> ?: 
[0.5399943]

[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.348 seconds

[Running] python -u "/home/neel/Documents/VS-Code_Projects/Machine_Lrn(PY)/tempCodeRunnerFile.py"
Random startin weights [[-0.16595599]
 [ 0.44064899]
 [-0.99977125]]
THe outputs are: - [[0.3262757 ]
 [0.5       ]
 [0.23762817]]
The adjustments are:- [[0.10504902]
 [0.14809799]
 [0.10504902]]
New synaptic weights after training: 
[[ 0.16031971]
 [ 0.94064899]
 [-0.76214308]]
Considering new situation [1, 0, 0] -> ?: 
[0.5399943]

[Done] exited with code=0 in 3.985 seconds
```

I have tried changing the iterations but the difference is very minor. I think the problem might be in one of my math(Sigmoid) functions. Other than that I think the dot multiplication at line 20 maybe a problem 'coz the adjustments look shifty to me....

Also, doesn't the 0.5 indicate that my network isn't learning as in it is just making a random guess?

**P.S:-** I think my problem isn't a duplicate one as it deals with the 'accuracy' of said model, while the question linked deals with the 'unwanted outputs'

Comment: I'm assuming this is just an exercise to familiarize yourself with feed-forward neural networks, but I'm putting this here just in case. Check out [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/) and [Keras](https://keras.io/) for libraries that do the heavy lifting for you and make training neural networks much easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Sigmoid_Derivative` function is **wrong**, something that has already been pointed out in a [previous question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57962057/unwanted-nan-output-in-python-neural-network/57963756#57963756); it should be:

```
def Sigmoid_Derivative(self, x):
    return self.Sigmoid(x) * (1-self.Sigmoid(x))
```

See the [Derivative of sigmoid function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78575/derivative-of-sigmoid-function-sigma-x-frac11e-x) thread at Math.SE, as well as the discussion [here](https://gist.github.com/jovianlin/805189d4b19332f8b8a79bbd07e3f598).

If correcting this still does not give the expected results, please do **not** alter the question above - instead, open a new one...

Comment: Thanx for the sympathies... Also I would like to update that the Sigmoid change did nothing for the accuracy. My post was regarding the accuracy of the model, but Prune has pointed it as a 'duplicate' question....

Comment: @neelg As alredy advised pls open a new question, BUT keep in mind: 1) you really train with only *three (3)* samples? 2) the accuracy calculation (or the result) is nowhere shown in your code - please see how to create a [MCVE] (emphasis on *minimal*...)